How to specify soft timeout in z3py
z3 has "-t" to set the soft timeout (in milli seconds). But when I use z3 in Python, I cannot set "-t" through "set_option" or "Optimize.set" API.
I try all the following methods. But it does not work.
opt = Optimize()
set_option("soft timeout, 600)
set_option("opt.soft_timeout", True)  # 600 s
opt.set("t", 60 * 1000)
opt.set("soft_timeout", True)
opt.set("soft timeout", True)
opt.set("smt.soft_timeout", True)

Please tell me how to set "-t" in the Python API of z3.

Use set as a method of the opt class. Something like this:
from z3 import *

opt = Optimize()
opt.set("timeout", 600)

I'm not sure if the parameter itself is called timeout, you need to double-check what it is really called. Otherwise the above syntax should work.

Thanks a lot. But "opt.set("timeout", 600)"  corresponds to "-T". It means the opt will return "unknown" when reaching the timeout.
Soft timeout means the opt will return the best solution found before the timeout.

Yeah, as I mentioned in the answer, you need to find the exact name of the parameter. You might have to look at the source code or ask the developers at their GitHub site.
